# Obtener el ultimo valor deseleccionado de un select multiple con JQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery

tengo el siguiente multi select:

```
<select multiple="multiple" id="select_empresas" name="my-select[]">
      <option value='elem_1'>elem 1</option>
      <option value='elem_2'>elem 2</option>
      <option value='elem_3'>elem 3</option>
      <option value='elem_4'>elem 4</option>
</select>
```

y el siguiente JQuery:

```
$('#select_empresas').on('change',function(e) {
   var unselected = $(this).find('option:last:not(:selected)').val();
   alert(unselected);
});
```

Lo que quiero hacer es que me muestre el `value` de la ultima opción desseleccionada, por ejemplo si `elem 2` esta seleccionada y posteriormente el usuario da `click` sobre ella y pasara a deseleccionarse, en ese momento es cuando quiero obtener el valor de dicho `option`, que seria `elem_2`.
Pero el problema es que no me muestra el valor que quiero.
Si alguien me puede ayudar se lo agradecería mucho

Answer (score 0):

Puedes probar algo como esto

```
<script>
$('#select_empresas option').on('click',function(e) {
    if($(this).is(":selected")){
        console.log($(this).text()+" Seleccionado");
    }else{
        console.log($(this).text()+" Deseleccionado");
    }
});
</script>
```

Saludos :)